# How to setup an app using browserify, babel, eslint, react/jsx, and jest (no gulp/grunt)?

Tags: reactjs, browserify, jestjs, babeljs, eslint

I would like to setup an app using

1. Browserify
2. BabelJS
3. ESLint
4. React(with jsx)
5. Jest

Npm as task manager (no gulp|grunt|brocoli)

Comment: And what is your specific question? Just install those modules and use them. There is nothing really to set up. You can add a script in your package.json with the commands you frequently run, but that's about it. You can learn more about scripts here: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: Have you done it with this particular techstack? It is a little tricky since you have to use the proper plugins to work with ESLint and Jest. This article has been useful but still need to figure out the jest part https://medium.com/javascript-scene/how-to-use-es6-for-isomorphic-javascript-apps-2a9c3abe5ea2

Comment: Almost everything is configured via package.json (or module specific config files). For jest + babel, have a look at https://github.com/babel/babel-jest

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all you need to install all those libraries with `npm`.

```
npm install --save-dev eslint, browserify, babelify, jest-cli
```

The package names self explain what lib is installed.

**Browserify:**

Assuming that `app/index.js` is your root file. You can add the following scripts to build and watch the source file.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "browserify app/index.js > public/js/bundle.js",
    "install": "npm run build",
    "watch": "watchify app/index.js -o public/js/bundle.js"
  }
```

**ES6 and JSX**

To compile ES6 and JSX, add the following to `package.json` :

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify"
    ]
  }
```

Now, browserify transforms your ES6 and JSX syntax to plain Javascript 5. For more transformations check this out https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/wiki/list-of-transforms.

**JEST**

To use  Jest add the following to package.json.

```
"scripts": {
   "test": ""
 }
```

After that, you can run tests using `npm test`. [Jest documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/getting-started.html#content)

**ESLINT**

If it's your first time using ESLint, you should set up a config file using `eslint --init` and then you need to add a new script to `package.json`.

For example:

```
"lint" : "eslint app/*.js"
```

Note, you need to specify all your source files you want to be lint in the above command.

Comment: Thanks this answer has a lot of detail. Enough to get me covered. What would possibly solve the question would be a example of es6 react hello world js-code and html.